# Get non Livedata from Room

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, android-livedata

I'm trying to get Data from the database using Room, and display it on a viewPager2,

however the dataset I send to viewpager, get updated every time the user make a modification to the Data and this mess with pageviewer2

How to get the data "news" from Room in a Non liveData and thread-safe way.

My first code :

In my fragment:

```
myDataModelView.getNews(category).observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<News>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<News> news) {
                    adapter.setNews(news);    //viewPager2 adapter
                }
            });
```

in myDataModelView:

```
public LiveData<List<News>> getNews(String category){
    return newsRepository.getNews(category);
}
```

in newsRepository:

```
public LiveData<List<News>> getNews(String category){
    return newsDao.getNews(category);
}
```

what I tried (Using Rxjava to get Data):

In my Fragment:

```
adapter.setNews(myDataViewModel.getFacts(category));
```

in myDataModelView:

```
public List<News> getNews(String category){
    return newsRepository.getNews(category);
}
```

in newsRepository:

```
public List<News> getNews(String category){
    Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Throwable {
            news = newsDao.getNews(category);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

                }
            });
    return news;
}
```

However, I received this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
```

Apparently, the viewPager adapter procced without waiting for dataset from the other thread.

Comment: "however the dataset I send to viewpager, get updated everytime the user make a modification to the Data" -- usually, that is a good thing! "How to get the data "news" from Room in a Non liveData and thread-safe way" -- have `getNews()` return `List<News>`, and call it from your own background thread.

Comment: You could create your own Observer that won't emit values after first is handled by itself.

Comment: @CommonsWare
Would you please check the question again, I updated it with more details, Yes I already tried your suggestion, but I missing something. 
Actually, when the user likes or read a news, I update the database which update the livedata and reset the pageviewer, that's why I don't want Livedata

Comment: @FlorescuCătălin
Would you please elaborate, I'm new to Room and Lifecycle

Comment: If you are going to use RxJava, I would have the repository return a `Single<List<News>>`.

Comment: @CommonsWare
Thank you, I'm new with Rxjava too, I will read about Single and try again.
I would appreciate if you could provide me with an example.

Comment: Sorry, while I use RxJava for some customer projects, I do not write about it much. My current Room samples are all in Kotlin, using coroutines for background operations.

Comment: @CommonsWare
Thank you, I've find some links online. I think I clear to me now